# How to close a program gracefully using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that I use to close a program by giving it its full exe path like "c:\run\myprogram.exe", and I want it to close it gracefully. I have been successful doing it forcefully using `Process, Close, %hWnd%` or `WinClose, ahk_id %iId%` but what I have been searching for is a method that would close a given program by its full path and then close it gracefully without force-closing it.

So far, I have this script:

```html
closeByExactPathToEXE(path) {
 for process in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process") {
  If (ePath  := process.ExecutablePath){
 
       iName  := process.Name
       iId    := process.ProcessId
       hWnd   := process.Handle
       ePath  := process.ExecutablePath
       SplitPath, ePath,, oPath,,,oDrive
      ;MsgBox %  "Letter:" oDrive "`nPath: "oPath "`npath" path
      
       If !InStr(ePath,path)
           Continue
 
       Loop, parse, exCludes, CSV
         If (iName = A_LoopField )  
            Continue
 
      ;My NO!!!
       If (iId = AmiNO) or (iName = A_ScriptName) 
           continue
   
       ;~ MsgBox %  "Letter:" oDrive "`nPath: "oPath 
       ;~ Process, Close, %hWnd%
       ;~ PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, %hWnd%  ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF060 = SC_CLOSE
       ;~ PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, %iName%  ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF060 = SC_CLOSE
       ;~ WinClose, ahk_id %iId%
       
  }
 }
}
```

the above script accepts the full path and should close the given program gracefully.
The nearest thing that I have found is this:

```
PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, %hWnd%  ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF060 = SC_CLOSE
```

and:

```
PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, %iName%  ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF060 = SC_CLOSE
```

however, they do not work with `%hWnd%` and `%iName%`.

Any possible solution or fix for the above script?

Answer (score 5):

First of all I'd try

```
WinClose, ahk_id %iId%
```

because

- **[WinClose](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm#Remarks)** ([WM_Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message) is the least forceful way:

  `WinClose, WinTitle`
- [**PostMessage**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) ([SC_Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message) is similar to WM_Close, but more forceful:

  `PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,,WinTitle`
- **[WinKill](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinKill.htm#Remarks)** attempts WM_Close, then attempts to kill the process:

  `WinKill, WinTitle`
- **[Process,Close](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm#Close)** is the most forceful way - equivalent to killing a process from the task manager:

  `Process,Close, ProcessName.exe`

Comment: WinClose did not produce the result I wanted.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that WinClose is the most graceful way. If, as you say, you have been successful doing it, you should continue to practice it.

Comment: The test was not successful

Comment: The next step could be `PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, ahk_exe ProcessName.exe` (after `WinWaitClose  ahk_id %iId%,, 2` and `if ErrorLevel`) and so on.

Comment: I don't want to give only exe name because there are multiple programs running by the same name, I want to give the full exe path to the closer program to close it

Comment: AFAIK the right syntax is `WinClose, ahk_id %hWnd%` and `PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,,  ahk_id %hWnd%`.